# Session start in struts 2.0

Tags: jsp, struts2

In asp.net, `global.asax` can have session_start event.
when user first visit the website, the session start, the event will trigger.
is that similar thing in struts or java specified?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener interface and register it in the web.xml. Methods of your implementation class will get called on session creation/destruction etc.

Entry in the web.xml will amount to something like below

```
<listener>
    <description>sessionListener</description>
    <listener-class>
        your.com.HttpSessionListenerImplementation
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is not related to struts but part of the servlet API and available in any servlet container

Answer (score 2):

Not in Struts2, well not as a built in feature. Of course you can remedy this with an interceptor/interceptor stack.

In Java EE the session is the duty of the application server. As such we should be able to assume we always have a session at least from the struts2 perspective.

This guy shows a pretty clear example of how to create an interceptor: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-creating-own-interceptor/

For a lot of details on interceptors see: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/interceptors.html

At the very bottom of the last link there is this link: [How do we get access to the session](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html) (from the Interceptor because in the action we would use SessionAware, although we could get at it this way too).

Generally you would want to so something special when someone logs in, and the sign-in action would be a good place to put what you want into the Session. For some reason you want something in place earlier so to reiterate:

1. Create custom SessionSetup interceptor
2. Register your interceptor and create a custom interceptor stack in struts.xml
3. Have all you packages use this stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session scope interceptor provided in struts 2 for session management.Following is a good use of it. You can specify if you want to start a session by a "start" param.

```
<interceptor-ref name="scope">
                <param name="type">start</param>
                <param name="session">revisionList,revisionManagmentDetails</param>
                <param name="key">revisionManagementSessionKey</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
```